# Unable to click radio button in Ruby ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, radio-button

I am displaying a form using ruby on rails as follows.

```
form do |f|
    f.semantic_errors *f.object.errors.keys

    # Form creation
    f.inputs "User" do
      f.input :first_name
      f.input :last_name
      f.input :email
      f.input :phone_number, required: false, as: :number
      f.input :password
      f.input :text_sms, as: :radio, :label => "Receive sms", :checked => "Yes"
    end
    f.action
end
```

This displays the form correctly, but the problem exists when I click the radio button. I am unable to select the radio button.
By default Yes is selected, but when I click on No, it doesn't allow me.

Any help will be appreciated.

Rails version : 4.2.0

Comment: did you find any fix for above issue?

Answer (score 1):

There is way, Try to replace your with

```
f.input :text_sms, as: :radio, :label => "Receive sms",:collection => [ ['Yes','yes',{:checked => true}], ['No','no'] ]
```

As given below:

```
form do |f|
    f.semantic_errors *f.object.errors.keys

    # Form creation
    f.inputs "User" do
      f.input :first_name
      f.input :last_name
      f.input :email
      f.input :phone_number, required: false, as: :number
      f.input :password
      f.input :text_sms, as: :radio, :label => "Receive sms",:collection => [ ['Yes','yes',{:checked => true}], ['No','no'] ]
    end
    f.action
end
```